# iframe youtube video doesn't control autoplay

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I am trying to embed youtube clip with iframe.

There is no issue with embedding it but autoplay doesn't work.

I tried this

```
<iframe
   width="1280"
   height="720"
   src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{videoId}?autoplay=1"
   frameborder="0"
   allow="autoplay"
   allowfullscreen
></iframe>
```

Am I missing something?

I am trying in local environment and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's work perfect, you need to check your {videoId}, this is an example:

```
<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LXb3EKWsInQ?showinfo=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `$` before the `{videoId}` so the videoId will be replaced with it's value.

```
<iframe
   width="1280"
   height="720"
   src=`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}?autoplay=1`
   frameborder="0"
   allow="autoplay"
   allowfullscreen
></iframe>
```